# Secondary implementation of protocol is ignored in favour of default implementation

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have another implementation of `ProtocolA` in such case? I tried something like this but it always calls default implementation and ignores other implementations.

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    func doAction()
}

extension ProtocolA {
    func doAction() {
        print("default implementation")
    }
}

class BaseClass: ProtocolA {
    func tapped() {
        doAction()
    }
}

class FirstClass: BaseClass {  }

class SecondClass: BaseClass, ProtocolB {  }

protocol ProtocolB { }

extension ProtocolA where Self: ProtocolB {
    func doAction() {
        print("another implementation")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I create an instance of SecondClass then calling doAction prints "another implementation" so I don't see what the issue is

Comment: In my case `doAction` is called from `BaseClass.tapped()`. May be that's the difference?

Comment: If I call tapped() from the SecondClass object I get "default implementation" printed but this is expected since SecondClass has not overriden tapped()

Comment: Yes you're right. Problem is `ProtocolA` actually has some calculated properties. `BaseClass` from its `viewDidLoad` used values from default implementation of `protocolA`. Now what i want is to configure `SecondClass` with different values using second implementation of `ProtocolA`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added sample code here https://gist.github.com/iamhaseebiqbal/fc55411f0baaa6b833b2902647388850